# Fetching query string parameters passed in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I have used [this](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/) tutorial to create a JS based widget. One thing I need to do is to pass query string parameters in JS file. I tried `document.location.href` but it gave the URL of page where widget was placed(which is quite obvious)

Code is given below:

```
<script src="http://example.com/widget.js?id=2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="widget"></div>
```

I need to fetch `id=2` which I can pass further.

Thanks

Comment: To get the querystring part of URL you need document.location.search. If you want to pull the parameter from URL look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery

Comment: @tabz100 My mistake. I just updated the question. Please check

Comment: Do you want to access id=2 in the widget.js file or the current page?

Comment: `id=2` It is a widget code.

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? It worked!!!

Comment: I thought you were asking something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your script an id then you can write:

```
<script src="http://example.com/widget.js?id=2" id="myscript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="widget"></div>

<script>
var myScript = document.getElementById('myscript');
var src= myScript.getAttribute('src');
//Get the id from the src based on parameter using Regular Expression
</script>
```

Comment: Where will I write this code? Do remember that the file where widget code block written will not be in my control

Comment: If you have no control over the widget code then how is the widget code using the parameters?

Comment: I mean I don't have controller of `caller` of widget.